# Why does readlines() gives out of index range if I use more than once?

Tags: python

If I store readlines() in a variable (the readlines list has more than one element), and indexing the variable, nothing goes wrong, i.e. say if my input made up of two rows,

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
data1 = data[0]
data2 = data[1]
```

this will be fine.

However, if I index the readlines directly, I will get index out of range error, i.e. with the same input,

```
import sys
data1 = sys.stdin.readlines()[0]
data2 = sys.stdin.readlines()[1]
```

gives index out of range error. Why does this happen?

I attached two images below to illustrate what I am trying to point out:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Because after one call to `readlines()`, you're at the end of the file, and there is nothing more to read

Comment: @roganjosh Yes!